# resetting the swank in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank, swank-clojure

Let me the describe the problem I am having in emacs.

I started the swank using the clojure-jack-in. I had to kill it for some reason, and killed swank using M-k (I dont know if there is a better way to shut it down).

Then I started inferior-lisp mode which actually has the same key bindings as the above. However now when I evaluate code it says "Not Connected", bcoz it is still looking for the previous swank server.

How do I reset it without restarting my emacs ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly (hence the comment): can't you simply kill the buffer that is not connected anymore and then re-issue a *clojure-jack-in*?  (this works for me and doesn't require restarting Emacs)